# How to correctly use vim.eval() in gVim?

Tags: vim

gVim allows to write Python code that can interact back with gVim by calling `vim.eval()`. It works for simple cases, like:

```
:py import vim; print(vim.eval("2 + 2"))
```

But if I try something more useful, for example, changing the value of an option, like so:

```
:py import vim; vim.eval("set runtimepath=~/.vim")
```

it always fails with the “*E121: Undefined variable: set*” error.

Is something wrong with my code or does `vim.eval()` simply not intended to be used outside of basic “2+2” evaluations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `vim.eval()` method evaluates a given argument as a Vim *expression*.  To
execute a Vim *command*, call the `vim.command()` method,

```
:py import vim; vim.command("set runtimepath=~/.vim")
```

See `:help python-eval` and `:help python-command`.